# DataGridView Sort Programmatically

Tags: datagridview

I have created my custom DataGridViewNumericTextBoxColumn derived from DataGridViewTextBoxColumn class.

When I call

```
this.HeaderDataGridView.Sort = Sort.Programmiticaly;
this.HeaderDataGridView.Sort(this.HeaderDataGridView.Columns[Utility.HEAD_X], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

It is working fine for integer type values but when the data contain double values it doesn't sort.

Answer (score 0):

What's the DataSource of the DataGridView?
Can the DataSource sort Double values programatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a binding source, you can simply set the .Sort property to the name of the column you want to sort on.  For example:

```
myBS = new BindingSource();
myBS.DataSource = DataSet.MY_TABLE;
myBS.Sort = "MY_COLUMN";
myGrid.DataSource = myBS;
```