# How Sort Datagridview?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DataGridView Sort Programmitically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005539/datagridview-sort-programmitically)

How Sort Datagridview ?

Comment: Programatically? Or using the build-in sort by clicking on column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the OnSorting event in your gridview.

This MSDN Article explains it fairly well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Oh, if only there was a [DataGridView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.  If only.